# Taxonomy, field collection and view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities

Here's my case:

- I have a content type with 
  -- field collection ***fc_file***
- I have a taxonomy term with
  -- the same existing field collection ***fc_file***
- In my field collection, I have:
  -- file pdf field ***fc_file_pdf***
- I've created a node and taxonomy term with a pdf file.

Here my problem:

- I created a view field collection.
- I have all the list a my pdf files from node and taxonomy
- But if I add a relationships *Field collection item : Entity with the fc_file* suppose to join to all the entity which have this field collection ( So in my case node and taxonomy ), but the result gives my only the list of the file from node.

Is somebody able to explain me why?